# Realice el programa que lee una cadena con números separados de espacios en blanco (pueden ser de 1 o más dígitos)

Tags: java

Realice el programa que lee una cadena con números separados de
espacios en blanco (pueden ser de 1 o más dígitos). Debe realizar la suma
de esos valores.

FRASE = 2 34 56 2 4 11

Respuesta= 2 + 34 + 56 + 2 + 4 + 11

Comment: Las tareas escolares/universitarias sólo son bienvenidas si se incluye lo que se ha intentado y/o las fuentes previas que se han consultado para resolver dicha tarea.

Comment: **Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo.** Para mas información revisa: [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Éstos son los pasos que puedo sugerirte:

- Declarar una variable `int` que contendrá el resultado
- Dividir la cadena en un array usando la función [`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), usando como parámetro el caracter espacio (" ").
- Recorres el array y por cada registro vas sumando a la variable resultado.

**NOTA**: debes verificar que en efecto, la cadena solamente contenga valores numéricos, de lo contrario no funcionará correctamente el algoritmo.

Comment: Preguntas que piden resolver tareas no se deben responder